# Method Error in Julia: thinks CSV is boolean and won't convert to string

Tags: csv, boolean, julia

I am trying to read a CSV file into Julia. When I open the file in Excel, its a 199x7 matrix of numbers. I am using the following code to create a variable, Xrel:

```
Xrel = CSV.read(joinpath(data_path,"Xrel.csv"), header=false)
```

However, when I try to do this, Julia produces:

`"MethodError: Cannot 'convert' an object of type Bool to an object of type String."`

`data_path` is defined in previous code to save space.
I've checked my paths and opened the CSV without a problem in R - it's only in Julia that I am having an issue.

I am confused as to why Julia is saying that my data is Boolean when its a matrix of numbers?
How can I resolve this to read in my CSV file?

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of CSV.jl are you using? Are you sure it's the most recent one? If yes, can you provide an example file to reproduce the bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use either `CSV.File()` or add a sink variable to `CSV.read()`

```
CSV.File(joinpath(data_path,"Xrel.csv"), header=false)
# or with a DataFrame as sink
using DataFrames
CSV.read(joinpath(data_path,"Xrel.csv"), DataFrame, header=false)
```

from the docs:

```
?CSV.read
CSV.read(source, sink::T; kwargs...) => T

Read and parses a delimited file, materializing directly using the sink function.

CSV.read supports all the same keyword arguments as CSV.File.
```